# Issue with Java program execution and input handling in a web-based code submission platform

Tags: javascript, java, html, express, spawn

I am currently building a basic web-based platform for Java coders, where users can submit their code to solve a given problem statement. I have implemented the front-end code using** HTML and JavaScript**, and the back-end server-side code using **Express.js and child_process**. However, I am facing issues with executing Java programs that require user input during runtime.
**
Here is a summary of my setup:**

Front-end: I have a form with a textarea where users can enter their Java code. Upon submission, the code is sent to the server for execution.
**Server-side:** The server receives the code, writes it to a temporary Java source file, and then uses spawn to execute the Java program. If the code compilation is successful, it proceeds to execute the compiled Java class.

Issue: The execution is working fine for Java programs without user input. However, for programs that require user input during runtime, I am not able to provide the input from the server side and receive the output on the front-end.
Here is an example of a Java program that requires user input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2, sum;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Number: ");
        num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number: ");
        num2 = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("Sum of these numbers: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Here is the Front End Code and Backend server code.

**Front End code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Code Submission Platform</title>
  <style>
    #codeForm {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
    }
    button {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #result {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Code Submission Platform</h1>


  <form id="codeForm">
    <label for="code">Enter your code:</label>
    <textarea id="code" name="code" placeholder="Enter your code here"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
    const form = document.getElementById('codeForm');
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Get the code from the textarea
      const code = document.getElementById('code').value;

      // Send the code to the backend API
      // Replace `API_URL` with the actual URL of your backend API
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/compile', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ code })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Display the result in the resultDiv
        resultDiv.innerHTML = `<h2>Result:</h2><pre>${data.result}</pre>`;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        resultDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>Error:</h2><p>Something went wrong. Please try again later.</p>';
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the **Backend code**.

```
const express = require('express');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON request bodies

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

// Endpoint to handle code submission
app.post('/compile', (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.body; // Assuming the code is sent as a JSON object with a "code" property

  if (!code) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: 'Code is missing' });
    return;
  }

  // Create a temporary Java source file
  const sourceFilePath = '/Users/shubham/Desktop/Coding Tool/HelloWorld.java';
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFileSync(sourceFilePath, code);

  // Run the Java compiler
  const compiler = spawn('javac', [sourceFilePath]);

  // Handle the compiler output
  compiler.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`Compiler output: ${data}`);
  });

  compiler.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.error(`Compiler error: ${data}`);
  });

  compiler.on('close', code => {
    if (code === 0) {
      // Execute the compiled Java class file
      const execution = spawn('java', ['-cp', '/Users/shubham/Desktop/Coding Tool', 'HelloWorld']);

      let executionOutput = '';

      execution.stdout.on('data', data => {
        executionOutput += data.toString();
      });

      execution.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.error(`Execution error: ${data}`);
      });

      execution.on('close', code => {
        console.log('Sending response:', executionOutput);
        res.send({ result: executionOutput });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Sending response: Compilation failed!');
      res.send({ result: 'Compilation failed!' });
    }
  });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have tried passing the input from the front-end to the server and then sending it to the Java program, but I'm not getting any output in response.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to handle user input for Java programs in my web-based code submission platform. How can I modify my server-side code to handle user input during runtime and receive the output on the front-end?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I was Expecting the Output 10 as result of First number 5 and Second Number 5 and returned back to frontend, but this inputs should be stored in server side, and if there is program with no input require it should work as it is.